# Need app to wait until a process is finished then continue

Tags: android, for-loop, sms, wait

I have read many post on here about this problem but I can not seem to get my code to wait until it finds the contact name before it continues and load my next activity. If it is a short sms it works fine but if it is a particularly long sms it crashes. Please any help.

**This is the new code as suggested below** the problem is still the same

```
     new LoaderAsyncTask().execute();

    }

public class LoaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    // Variables to pass data between doInBackground() and onPostExevute() here

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

         Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(smsSender));
                Cursor cursor = ((Context) contexts).getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID },
                    null, null, null);
                contactId = "";
                name="unknown";
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                    contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
                    name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }


        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         ////////////////////////////////////
        // start a new task before dying

        intents.setClass((Context) contexts, SendSMSActivity.class);
        intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // pass Serializable object
        intents.putExtra("PhoneNumber", smsSender);
        intents.putExtra("smsBody", smsBody);
        intents.putExtra("SmsMessageId", SmsMessageId);
        intents.putExtra("contactId", contactId);
        intents.putExtra("SenderName", name);
        // start UI
        ((Context) contexts).startActivity(intents);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help to specify what language you're writing in..

Comment: he is making an Android app, Alex

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to start an AsyncTask to get your Contact name. Then call `startActivity()` in the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` method, which runs back on the main UI thread. So in essence, you kick off an AsyncTask, let it get the contact name asynchronously, then call `startActivity()` only when it finishes.

Here's a nice tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

And the AsyncTask documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Scroll down to "Using AsyncTask" in this guide:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

Comment: Thanks for the tip I have tried to use this code in the Activity I started from the sms receiver above but it does not seem to wait until the find contactname

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        new LoaderAsyncTask().execute();
    }

}

public class LoaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    // Variables to pass data between doInBackground() and onPostExevute() here

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // yoyr loader stuff here

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // update UI or call ActivityB here

         ////////////////////////////////////
        // start a new task before dying
        Intent = ... // not shown in your code
        intent.setClass(context, SendSMSActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // pass Serializable object
        intent.putExtra("PhoneNumber", smsSender);
        intent.putExtra("smsBody", smsBody);
        intent.putExtra("SmsMessageId", SmsMessageId);
        intent.putExtra("contactId", contactId);
        intent.putExtra("SenderName", name);
        // start UI
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Check the AsyncTask doc for more detailed explanation of the class in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the suggestion I tried the above code but the code does not seem to wait before continuing to Activity B. I put the find user name code in the do in background and if the sms is short it finds the name but if the sms is very long then the name comes back as unknown which I am guessing means the find name did not finished before it continued to Activity B. I just do not understand why.